# Make Orchard works with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, nhibernate, orchardcms

My objective is to make Orchard CMS works with MongoDB.

I look on Google for some resources about how to start with the integration but I didn't find any documentation on this.

Is anyone already make Orchard works with a NoSQL DB ? 
What the first step in order to modify default database from SQL Server to MongoDB ?

I read this documentation:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/the-shift-how-orchard-painlessly-shifted-to-document-storage-and-how-it-ll-affect-you

read [on release note from 1.8](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-1-8-Release-Notes) that

```
Performance improvements by unleashing the power of the document db architecture built in Orchard
```

But I can't figure what that's mean exactly

In the Orchard Uservoice, there are already 43 votes for extension for MongoDB

https://orchard.uservoice.com/forums/50435-general/suggestions/2262572-mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchard 1 stores a lot of its data encoded as XML in a special column of its content item table. That is all it means. The database still has to be relational, and still has to work with nHibernate. That excludes MongoDB.

Orchard 2's data story on the other hand is built for document storage, or more precisely it separates storage from querying, and can work with pretty much anything for the storage part.

So MongoDB as a content store for Orchard 1 will never happen, but it will for Orchard 2.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer @bertrant-le-roy !! Is the default database for Orchard 2 will be MongoDb? Or officially supported? Is there a repo with alpha or beta version that I can experiment?

Comment: No, the default won't be MongoDB, and to be clear, I was just saying that support for it will be easy, not that it will be there out of the box. The repo is here: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard2

Comment: Ok thanks again, at January 2016 I will work with a team that makes Orchard (v 1) working with MongoDB, I think there will be some opportunities to share some code about this with the Orchard Core Team on Orchard (v 2).